# Index file causing error with Jest when I import

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I am getting an error when I import a file for testing.

This is the only line in the file:
`import Cart from '../../components/cart/Cart';`

This is the error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')

      27 |
      28 | // Form Blocks
    > 29 | export { default as CustomerInfo } from './formBlocks/CustomerInfo';
         |                  ^
      30 | export { default as Address } from './formBlocks/Address';
```

Note: `CustomerInfo` is not used in the file I am trying to import.  If I comment out that line we get the same error on a different line that is also not related to the component I am trying to import.

The error points to an index file for all of the components.

[image]

This also happens if I change the import to any of these variations:

`import Cart from '../../components/cart/Cart';`

`import { Cart } from '../../components';`

`import { Cart } from '../../components/index';`

etc

I also get the same error if I try to import a file that doesn't exist

`import ThisFileDoesntExist from '../../components/index';`

Why is it looking at the index file if I import it directly from the component file?

Is there some extra config I can add to tell Jest not to look at the index file?